# Prevent or revert drag & drop in Primefaces tree

Tags: ajax, jsf, primefaces, drag-and-drop, tree

I have a Primefaces 4 tree in which I want enable drag and drop. But I have constraints which do not allow to move some node types to other (i.e. only leafs can be moved and they can be moved only to the same type of parent nodes).

How can I prevent or cancel such drag and drop operation if the constraints fail? I would expect the onDragDrop event handler to return false or so in such cases but this method has void return type. I can check constraints in event handler but the drag and drop operation is already done.

What to do here?

Comment: It's not a question of a particular code, you can check Primefaces show case. The framework simply seems to lack a constraint handling mechanism here.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Primeface Tree Drag & Drop](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18999476/primeface-tree-drag-drop)